# H2O-based random forest model predicts always 1 when converted to POJO

Tags: machine-learning, pojo, h2o

I am new to machine learning, doing prediction on an Imbalanced dataset using random forest algorithm. I built the model in R, the response variable is a binary categorical one (0,1). The random forest model built in R produces a proper classification, but when this model is been converted to h2o pojo for building an application, the model only returns "1" as the response.

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATE: the answer was written before OP was edited to clarify that the problem emerges only *after* the conversion to POJO - see comments]

I bet that your dataset is highly *imbalanced*, i.e. you have much more 1's in your training set than 0's.

Even if you get a good accuracy during model fit, in such cases accuracy as a metric is meaningless, and you should use precision, recall, and the confusion matrix instead - google "class imbalance" for more.

As an example, if 85% of your training labels are 1's, you can have a 85% accuracy "classifier" simply (and naively) by classifying *all* samples as 1 (which, arguably, is not what exactly you are looking to do).

Comment: I get a proper prediction while running the model in Rstudio, but when I run the same model after building h2o POJO  and run on gradle builder I get this error of having the same class output of 1 for all my test data

Comment: @VenkataKrishnan and why exactly you didn't include this info in your post?